# How to append items in multiple lists having same index into their original lists?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, random, append

I have an arbitrary number of lists, 3 taken here for example. The lists will have the same number of items and I want to append the items having the same index into their original list. This has to be done with some probability.

```
import random

individuals = 6
lists = 3

L1 = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'a', 'a']
L2 = ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'b', 'b']
L3 = ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'c', 'c']

for i in range(1, lists+1):
    for j in range(0, 6): 
      if random.random() <= 0.8:  
        ((eval(f'L{i}'))).append((eval(f'L{i}{[j]}')))
      else:
        pass

for i in range(1, lists+1):
    print(eval(f'L{i}'))
```

What I want is that L1[0], L2[0] and L3[0] be appended into their original list if they satisfy a probability. Then we do the same for L1[0], L2[1] and L3[2] and so on until we run out of the original items(6 in this example). If the probability is not satisfied, all items having the same index will not get appended.

The current result is giving me unequal sized lists at the end. The lists should be equal-sized as what I need is either all lists get appended at once or they don't.

Current result:

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'a', 'a', 'A', 'A', 'a', 'a']
['B', 'B', 'B', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'b', 'b']
['C', 'C', 'C', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'c', 'c']
```

Comment: Not sure to catch the problem but what is sure is that if you add items according a random process, there is abviously no reason why the output lists will have the same length. Maybe I'm missing the point.

Comment: You have a call to `random.random()` in your  `if` test, which means you have no prior control over whether `append()` will be called for a given list and so the number of `append`s may be different for each list. And please stop using `eval` like that. It's unnecessary. Make a dict called `L` and then use `L[1]` instead of `L1` and use `L[i]` instead of `eval(f'L{i}')`.

Comment: what I want is all lists to get appended if they satisfy a probability. So if probability = 0.9, the code appends L1 with L1[0], L2 with L2[0] and L3 with L3[0]. If probability was 0.2, none of the lists gets appended. And we do the same for all items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you only need to reverse the order of the two for loops:

```
import random

individuals = 6
lists = 3

L1 = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'a', 'a']
L2 = ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'b', 'b']
L3 = ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'c', 'c']

for j in range(0, 6): 
    p = random.random()             # Random probability (same for all lists)
    if p <= 0.8:
        for i in range(1, lists+1): # all list get appended
            ((eval(f'L{i}'))).append((eval(f'L{i}{[j]}')))

for i in range(1, lists+1):
    print(eval(f'L{i}'))
```

**Output**

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'a', 'a', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'a', 'a']
['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'b', 'b', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'b', 'b']
['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'c', 'c', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'c', 'c']
​
```

Comment: I see my mistake now

Comment: @user15849775--things are often clear in retrospect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand.Maybe you say this.

```
for j in range(0, 6):
      if random.random() <= 0.8:
          for i in range(1, lists + 1):
              ((eval(f'L{i}'))).append((eval(f'L{i}{[j]}')))
      else:
        pass
```